# "Edit" Layout Multi-Select Picklist Width

Tags: page-layout

When in Edit mode on my Account object, multi select picklist lightbox are not the same width. This is causing my page layout to get messed up. What can I do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay - just seen the edit to the original question so updated answer:

Sadly you can only fix this by having the largest picklist values be of the same size. The width is calculated to fit these maximums and so the workaround is to expand them to all have a longest entry of the same size.

[Pat Patterson has created a VF component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html) which I would imagine you could style if this is really a must have - but I would highly recommend against it.

Comment: I updated the question with an image

Comment: Updated answer.